# Error occurred when installing package 'xlsx'

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, xlsxwriter

am trying to install XLSX package from interpreter and am getting this error
(Error occurred when installing package 'xlsx'), noting that pip is updated already

how to solve it ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9E3b.jpg)

I had updated pip, i used CMD to check about my python version seems everything is ok, but i dont know where is the issue

Comment: **DO NOT** post images of code,data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.  Images can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Also, refrain from posting links to problem definitions and/or explanations Instead, incorporate the explanation into your question directly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does the 'details' tell you?

Comment: @moken, This is the details: (ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xlsx (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for xlsx)

Comment: And that answers your question. There is no package `xlsx`

Comment: If you are trying to install `xlsxwriter` then its `pip install xlsxwriter` or search in Pycharm for `'XlsxWriter'` by John McNamara

Comment: @moken, When I search in interpreter packages I found XLSX through this path (Pycharm, settings, Python Interpreter, available packages) and I tried to download it but it didn't work

Comment: Yes,  I checked pycharm and you are right it does show up in the list but appears its not (no longer) a valid package.